# How do I change the port that I use to remotely access a Windows (10) computer?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

How do I go about changing the port that I use for remote desktop on Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Start Registry Editor, and locate and then click the following registry subkey:
>
>    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
> 2. On the Edit menu, click Modify, and then click Decimal.
> 3. Type the new port number, and then click OK.
> 4. Quit Registry Editor.
> 5. Restart the computer.
>
> **Note:** When you try to connect to this computer using RDP, you must input the new port.

Source https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306759

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing) and make sure you "block quote" quoted material ([Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help)). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Okay, I'll know for next time!

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Firewall Rules and change the default port(s) OR make a new rule for whatever port you want then use IP:PORT as your address.